# how to convert string to int in Java

Tags: java, string, int

I'm working on Caesar cipher example in which I want that it get different keys from user and finally one key decrypt the original text , but I got a problem, here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner user_input= new Scanner(System.in);
    String plainText = "University of malakand";
    String key;
    key = user_input.next();

    Ceasercipher cc = new Ceasercipher();

    String cipherText = cc.encrypt(plainText,key);
    System.out.println("Your Plain  Text :" + plainText);
    System.out.println("Your Cipher Text :" + cipherText);

    String cPlainText = cc.decrypt(cipherText,key);
    System.out.println("Your Plain Text  :" + cPlainText);
}
```

it shows an error on this line

```
    String cipherText = cc.encrypt(plainText,key);
```

it shows me error on key incompatible types:

> String cannot be converted into int

What can I do?

Comment: First, what does `String cannot be converted into int` mean to you?

Comment: You did not think it necessary to show what value you entered ?

Answer (score 2):

Ask following questions to your self first.

- What your method want as parameter?
- Why both are Incompatible?
- What `String cipherText = cc.encrypt(plainText,key);` mean?
- key is `String` or `int`?

Use methods like `Integer.parseInt(String value)` or `Integer.valueOf(String value)` for conversion.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to convert a `String` to `int`, not a `int` to `String`. To do that, you can use `Integer.parseInt()`:

```
int someInt = Integer.parseInt(someString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
String cipherText = cc.encrypt(plainText,Integer.parseInt(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing String and the method parameter seems to have int and hence the error. You might want to convert your `string` to `int` using int `keyInt = Integer.parseInt(key);` and similarly for plain text if necessary and then pass keyInt and/or plainTextInt as the parameters.